# Random integers inside a string for "mask" phone numbers in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I would just like to replace the phone numbers inside a string with a random one.
Keep in mind that the replaced value will have to have the same length as the original one.

Here is my output:

| PhoneNumberEdit after using the script below | PhoneNumber | Output desired |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 00000031 | 20538746 | 22581610 |
| 41240312 | 86387520 | 86387520 |
| 02022222 | 29450805 | 04543572 |
| 3333333333 | 4522660402 | 3485068402 |
| 3323200636 | 4524270646 | 0495720942 |
| 32222332 | 31122001 | 03947480 |
| ID er et barn 21468018 | ID er and barn 55113153 | ID er and barn 30394021 |

I tried with this code but the randomization does not work as I would like. The values are not really that distinct or that randomized. (You can see how sequences of '2222' are repeated in the third row or '3333333' in the 4th)

The function I am using now is:

```
select replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(
                        PhoneNumber, '0', ABS(CHECKSUM(NEWID()))%10),
                        '1', ABS(CHECKSUM(NEWID()))%10),
                        '2', ABS(CHECKSUM(NEWID()))%10), 
                        '3', ABS(CHECKSUM(NEWID()))%10),
                        '4', ABS(CHECKSUM(NEWID()))%10),
                        '5', ABS(CHECKSUM(NEWID()))%10),
                        '6', ABS(CHECKSUM(NEWID()))%10),
                        '7', ABS(CHECKSUM(NEWID()))%10),
                        '8', ABS(CHECKSUM(NEWID()))%10),
                        '9', ABS(CHECKSUM(NEWID()))%10), * from dbo.PhoneNumbers
```

Comment: Depending on your scenario, you may also want to consider [Dynamic Data Masking](https://learn.microsoft.com/sql/relational-databases/security/dynamic-data-masking), as it's easier to maintain.

Comment: How can anyone see your results? There's no schema for dbo.PhoneNumbers, no sample data, and no code for dbo.ReplaceLetters().

Comment: Done. Sorry for unclarities.

Comment: Oh, wait, I see your issue. :P You are chaining `REPLACE` calls, which means that you first replace every `9`, then every `8`, then every `7`, each with the same new digit... in doing so you're making it much more likely for repeats to start occurring, because you're replacing digits you already replaced, when you should be replacing each of them only once.

Comment: In the following article I wrote multiple option to get random string. In most solutions you have option to control the length using input parameter, which can cover your need: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/21196.t-sql-random-string.aspx and if you want to use SQLCLR then here is the solution https://ariely.info/Blog/tabid/83/EntryId/134/SQL-Random-String-using-CLR.aspx

Comment: What you want is a way to replace any sequence of digits by an equal-length sequence of random digits. Unfortunately this is not simple to do in T-SQL, as there is no easy way to repeatedly replace patterns. It's slightly easier if you know every string can't contain more than one such sequence, but even then there's only clunky approaches. Generating a (not too long) random sequence is the relatively easy part, that could be done with (for example) `SELECT RIGHT(CONCAT(REPLICATE('0', 18), ABS(CONVERT(BIGINT, CRYPT_GEN_RANDOM(8)))), 10)` (replace `10` for any other length less than 18).

Comment: How do you find the phone inside the string?!? What fi there are other numbers which are not phones. Do you want to replace all numbers in he string?!?

Answer (score 0):

following syntax gives you a n-digit random number

```
SELECT ABS(CHECKSUM(NewId())) %1000  --Three-digit number
SELECT ABS(CHECKSUM(NewId())) %10000  --four-digit number 
SELECT ABS(CHECKSUM(NewId())) %100000  --five-digit number 
SELECT ABS(CHECKSUM(NewId())) %10....00  --n-digit number 
                               ---n----
```

to get your result you should change get the **length** of phone number and use **power** function and change the query as follows

```
SELECT 
  Abs(
    Checksum(
      Newid()
    )
  ) % Power(---create a Multiplication of 10
    10, 
    (
      Len([PhoneNumber])---get length of string
    )
  ) as PhoneNumber ,* 
from 
  dbo.PhoneNumbers
```

Comment: Since `CHECKSUM` only yields `INT`s, it isn't possible to generate more than 9 digits with this method. It furthermore is not guaranteed to produce *exactly* the desired number of digits, only *at most* (consider the case where the outcome is `0`).